# Как отключить логгер в Hibernate (SLF4J)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, slf4j, логирование

В общем, такая беда: логгер начал сходить с ума, он начал выводить в консоль абсолютно ненужные вещи, которые я его не просил (мы вместе с другом программируем и у него при таком же самом коде логгер выводит только то, что ему сказали). Есть ли возможность его отключить? Перепробывал все советы в StackOverflow, но ничего не помогает. Людям говорят, что логгер — SLF4J, а они пишут про LOG4J, поэтому — проблема у меня с логгером ***`SLF4J`***. Фото того, что он выводит: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6ZZq.jpg. Если посмотреть справа на скролл, то можно понять, что подобного текста там настолько много, что вприцнипе невозможно найти то, что нужно. Пробывал также указаывать в Hibernate Properties: https://i.stack.imgur.com/deVSO.jpg. Он как будто не хочет отключаться. Зависимость самая обычная:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
```

В общем, хочу сказать, что после подключения я логгер ни как не пытался настраивать и он так себя ведет прямо, что называется, "с коробки". Какие совету по его отключению или хотя бы настроить уровень логгирования?

Так же, на всякий случай, выкладываю весь конфигурационный класс:

```
package classes.chapter8.intro.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"classes.chapter8"})
public class JpaConfig {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JpaConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        try {
            EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder databaseBuilder =
                    new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();

            return databaseBuilder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                    .addScripts("jdbc/db/schema.sql", "jdbc/db/test-data.sql")
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Embedded DataSource bean cannot be created!", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProp = new Properties();
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", false);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.format_sql", false);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", false);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 50);
        return hibernateProp;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("classes/chapter8");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311408/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console-output

Comment: вы бы добавили [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) того, как вы используете класс

Comment: Тут можно даже и не добавлять примера как использую класс, даже если я все логгеры выключу и не буду ими пользоваться в прицнипе, то логгер все равно выводит всякий бред в консоль. Это проблема исключительно внутренних настроек. Конфигурационный класс я символически скинул, возможно, я что то упустил в настройках

Comment: DmitryD, я тоже гуглить умею, спасибо. Я был на этой статье, читайте внимательно вопрос, пожалуйста))))))

Comment: Ну, во-первых, SLF4J не логгер, это универсальный API для логгирования, а вот Log4j, например, это уже конкретная реализация этого API. Смотрите какие реализации логгеров тянуться в проект (ЕМНИП, hibernate в транзитивных зависимостях тащит свой логгер). Плюс смотрите с какими параметрами стартует приложение. Кто его стартует? IDEA, gradle, maven? Судя по скринам где-то в настройках для пакета org.hibernate.cfg включен уровень логгирования = DEBUG. Вам никто не мешает заглянуть в исходники классов, которые сыпят логи, и посмотреть на что они опираются при выводе логов. Ну а дальше дело техники